# How to use smb protocol with Sensetalk

Tags: protocols, drive, smb, eggplant

Read a file with sensetalk smb protocol
Is this correct?

put "username" into username
put "password" into password
put "server_name" into serverName
put "path/to/file.txt" into filePath

## Create an SMBConnection object

put SMBConnection(username, password, "client_name", serverName, use_ntlm_v2:true) into conn

## Connect to the server

put conn.connect("server_ip", 139) into connStatus

## Check if the connection was successful

if connStatus is not "SUCCESS" then
logError "Failed to connect to server: " & connStatus
else
# Read the file
put conn.openFile(filePath, "r") into fileObj
put fileObj.read() into fileData

```
# Print the file contents
log fileData

# Close the file and the connection
fileObj.close()
conn.close()
```

end if

////write to a file
put "username" into username
put "password" into password
put "server_name" into serverName
put "path/to/file.txt" into filePath

## Create an SMBConnection object

put SMBConnection(username, password, "client_name", serverName, use_ntlm_v2:true) into conn

## Connect to the server

put conn.connect("server_ip", 139) into connStatus

## Check if the connection was successful

if connStatus is not "SUCCESS" then
logError "Failed to connect to server: " & connStatus
else
# Write to the file
put conn.openFile(filePath, "w") into fileObj
put "This is some text that we're writing to the file" into fileData
fileObj.write(fileData)

```
# Close the file and the connection
fileObj.close()
conn.close()
```

end if

To read a file on a network drive with this method.